# Why customize <br> not working in Chrome and IE?

Tags: css, layout, cross-browser

I am using `<br>` that work differently in every browser so I decide to set style of "br" become

```
<br style='margin:15px;'/>
```

It works perfectly on Firefox but not working in IE and Chrome..Any suggestion??

Comment: replace be `<br />` with a more semantic element, e.g. `<p>` and avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: Could you show us (preferably on http://jsfiddle.net/) how you’re using this `<br>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<br>` are inline elements and not block elements, keep that in mind.

```
  br {
       display: block;
       margin: 10px 0;
    }
```

This is a very very very very ... very very dirty version, and although its not browser compatible. You should not do it and I would recommend you NOT to copy that code, consider rewriting your code. Styling `<br/>` is very very very BAD. I'm in the very mood today ;-). Also you should not use `<br>` in your code, because **HTML** is generally for *markup* and **CSS** is for *styling*. But it's my opinion.
Your code would be more flexible if you use `<p>` to wrap your text and set your paddings and margin there instead of the use of `<br/>` which 1. messes up your code and 2. messes up your styling because you are mixing styling and HTML in one file, which makes it bad to manipulate in the future because you don't know hmm have i set this style inline or in an external css file.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to wrap your text with `<p>` tags, defining them as paragraphs.

```
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
```

and CSS:

```
p { margin-bottom: 15px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not apply styles to a `<br />` tag, because it's not really a stylable element. It's more like a flag for forcing a line break.

You may be better off applying styles to a containing element (for example, wrap the text before the `<br />` in a `<div>` and style ther).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could show us how you want to use this style, then we can come back with a more 'standard' method / markup. I guess you might have had trouble setting a margin on another element so you've used the `<br />` tag.

Pop up what you've tried and let's work it out.